# Finding optimal taxation policy- constrained optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I need to solve two constrained optimization problems where the second problem depends on the results of the first.

The agents in my economy maximize utility: $$\max_{c,d,l} p\ln(c)+\ln(d)+\ln(l)$$ 
subject to a budget constraint: $$(1-t)w(1-l)+T \ge c+(1+\tau)d$$
where choose $c-$ denotes consumption of non-durable goods, $d$-consumption of durable goods, and $l$- denotes labor supply.

There are two agents in the economy, high skilled and low skilled (denoted by $X_h$ and $X_l$, respectively), so solving for each of them will yield the demand functions: $$c_l (t,\tau,T), c_h (t,\tau,T), d_l(t,\tau,T), d_h (t,\tau,T)$$ and the supply functions: $$l_l (t,\tau,T), l_h (t,\tau,T)$$

This part I can calculate myself but the next part is where I'm struggling.
Given these demand and supply functions, the government needs to choose the tax parameters ($t,T,\tau$) that maximize the overall welfare:
$\max_{t,\tau,T} p\ln(c_l)+p\ln(c_h)+2(1-p)\ln(\frac{c_l +c_h }{2})+\ln(d_l)+\ln(d_h)+\ln(l_l)+\ln(l_h)$
subject to the resource constraint:
$t(w_h(1-l_h)+w_l(1-l_l))+\tau (d_l+d_h) \ge 2T$
Where $t$ is the income tax, $T$ is the lump sum tax and $tau$- denotes the tax on durable consumption.
So my first problem is this: how do I solve each agent's constrained optimization problem to find their demand and labor supply functions? And once I've found those, how can I use them to solve the governments optimal tax policy?
I've tried manually defining the demand and labor supply functions, and then deriving the social welfare function manually and using solve to find the result:
[image]

But I'm getting a weird result (see image)

[image]
I don't understand what <<1>> means or <<32>>...

Once I will have all of this figured out, the final part will be to check the sensitivity of the overall welfare function:
$p\ln(c_l)+p\ln(c_h)+\ln(d_l)+\ln(d_h)+\ln(l_l)+\ln(l_h)$ to $p$.
I want to see if the overall welfare is maximal when $p=1$ and if it is strictly increasing in $p$. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide your code with a clear indication as to the *Mathematica* coding related issue you have.

Comment: Also describe your variables and analysis.

Comment: I've tries to be more specific as you requested, does this help explain my problem?

Comment: just to address the specific question the `<<>>` are indicating large output that has been omitted so the essential form of the result can be displayed compactly.  Hit "Show Full Ouput" to see the whole thing. (Beware if its really big its liable to overwhelm your computer)  You should include actual code, not images by the way.

Comment: as a suggestion, it is often useful to work through a problem with specific numeric example values assigned to your parameters wherever possible.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the solution I got for further computations? for instance, can I assign a new variable $t$ to be the solution I received for $t$? and then do the same for $T$ and $tau$?

Comment: I have answer the question of Nofar duani  in the question 

About http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135009/finding-optimal-taxation-policy-constrained-optimization

Comment: It is very nice of you to seek to help the OP, but I can't agree wrt closing the question. The question as originally posed had very little, if anything to with Mma ... it was about setting up a utility maximisation problem subjection to a budget constraint, with supply and demand functions blah blah and on and on it went ... There is an art to asking questions, of honing the question down to the issue at hand ... and this question, as posed, did not even get to close to being a mma question.

Comment: Wolfies I do not say you are untrue. But It is not evident to know how to ask a question the first time one enter in this type of site. Then OD as corrected her question an shown that she has tried to fin a way to the solution. So perhaps the advice to the first users must be reinforced explaining that a question must be direct and code documented.

Comment: I never vote to close a question if there are no comments. At time of closing, the poster had not provided any relevant code, and now it only has a picture of code.
I agree this question can remain open with answer, but only if the question is changed to how the original question should have been posed. This is not the place to complain about how the site is run.

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest way to solve the individual problem

```
obj := p Log[c] + Log[d] + Log[l]
constraint := (1 - t) w (1 - l) + T - c - (1 + τ) d
log = obj - λ constraint
grad = Grad[log, {c, d, l, λ}]
sol = Solve[{grad[[1]] == 0, grad[[2]] == 0, grad[[3]] == 0, 
   grad[[4]] == 0}, {c, d, l, λ}]
```

which gives

```
{{c -> (p T + p w - p t w)/(2 + p), 
  d -> (T + w - t w)/((2 + p) (1 + τ)), 
  l -> (-T - w + t w)/((2 + p) (-1 + t) w), λ -> (-2 - p)/(
   T + w - t w)}}
```

Now your two agents are identical so the collective problem can be simplified to

```
colobj := 2 p Log[c] + 2 (1 - p) Log[c] + 2 Log[d] + 2 Log[l]
colconstraint := t w (1 - l) + τ d - T
colobj1 = colobj /. sol
colconstraint1 = colconstraint /. sol
log1 = colobj1 - μ colconstraint1
grad1 = FullSimplify[Grad[log1, {t, τ, T,μ}]]
sol = Solve[{grad1[[1, 1]] == 0, grad1[[1, 2]] == 0, 
   grad1[[1, 3]] == 0,grad1[[1, 3]] == 0}, {t, τ, T}]
```

Which in its turn gives

```
{{t -> (-1 + p)/p, τ -> (1 - p)/p, 
 T -> ((-1 + p) w)/(3 p), μ -> -(6/w)}}
```

Hope this will answer your question.