# Assigning variables after solve

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I have a set of 4 equations that I solved using the Solve function, resulting in the following output:
[image]

I want to use these solution for further computations, so basically, I want to assign new functions for $t,T$ and $tau$, according to the solution I got, so that I can later use them in a different function. How can I do that?

I've reveiwed similar questions as you suggested, but I'm affraid it's not working. Here is my code:

```
cl[T_, t_, tau_] = (p T + p wl - p t wl)/(2 + p)
dl[T_, t_, tau_] = (T + wl - t wl)/((2 + p) (1 + tau))
ll[T_, t_, tau_] = (-T - wl + t wl)/((2 + p) (-1 + t) wl)
ch[T_, t_, tau_] = (p T + p wh - p t wh)/(2 + p)
dh[T_, t_, tau_] = (T + wh - t wh)/((2 + p) (1 + tau))
lh[T_, t_, tau_] = (-T - wh + t wh)/((2 + p) (-1 + t) wh)
```

Thanks

Comment: Nofar have you seen my comment on your last question ? I have provided and answer in another question ?

Comment: cyrille.piatecki - no, When I pressed the link attached it kept sending me back to my question

Comment: Better use replacement lists like `mu /. sol` for example. See previous duplicate answers.

Comment: Sorry I was correcting copies look at the question About http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135009/finding-optimal-taxation-policy-constrained-optimization and if it doesn't open send me a message --- you can find easily my adress --- I will send you the code